# Rpsec "no route matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a strange situation.
I have such code in my routes.rb:

```
concern :votable do
  post :vote_up, on: :member, controller: :votes
  post :vote_down, on: :member, controller: :votes
end

resources :questions, concerns: [:commentable, :votable], shallow: true do
  resources :answers, concerns: [:commentable, :votable]
end
```

So, it gives me helpers `vote_up_question` and `vote_up_answer` via 'post':

```
vote_up_answer POST   /answers/:id/vote_up(.:format)                 votes#vote_up
vote_down_answer POST   /answers/:id/vote_down(.:format)               votes#vote_down
vote_up_question POST   /questions/:id/vote_up(.:format)               votes#vote_up
vote_down_question POST   /questions/:id/vote_down(.:format)             votes#vote_down
```

My votes_controller:

```
  before_action :load_parent

  def vote_up
    current_user.vote_for(@parent)
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Voted up"
  end

  private

  def load_parent
    resource, id = request.path.split("/")[1, 2]
    @parent = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end
```

Everything works perfect, BUT!
I want to test that `load_parent` method with RSpec:

```
RSpec.describe VotesController, type: :controller do
  let(:question) {create(:question)}
  let(:answer) {create(:answer, user_id: user, question_id: question)}
  let(:user) {create(:user)}
  before(:each) do |example|
    sign_in user if example.metadata[:sign_in]
    request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = question_path(question) if example.metadata[:redirect_back]
  end


  describe 'POST #vote_up', sign_in: true, redirect_back: true  do
    it 'should assign question to @parent' do
      post vote_up_question_path(question)
      expect(assigns(:parent)).to eq 'question'
    end
  end
end
```

And here is a problem:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/questions/1/vote_up", :controller=>"votes"}
```

What is wrong? I also tried different ways to make a clear route, like `post :vote_up, question_id: question`, but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you show ``rake routes`` output?

Comment: Added part of it to the question.

Comment: Have you tried `post :vote_up, id: question.id` ?

Comment: yes, and the result is quite strange - `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Answer with 'id'=1`

Comment: I can test the answer case, but not the question case - so it is not the correct solution. And, still, I can not understand why this happens

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec I don't feel its correct to put the polymorphism into the controller layer, but you should be able to test the functionality with request specs.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 let!(:question) {create(:question)}
 let!(:user) {create(:user)}
 let!(:answer) {create(:answer, user_id: user, question_id: question)}
```

let is lazy-evaluated so if it isn't invoked in this block it might be undefined.

Then do:

```
 describe 'POST #vote_up', sign_in: true, redirect_back: true  do
it 'should assign question to @parent' do
  post :vote_up, id: question.id
  expect(assigns(:parent)).to eq 'question'
end
```

end